# Server Side rendering in React boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-boilerplate

I am using a boilerplate for react application https://www.reactboilerplate.com/

It doesn't provide SSR and now for SEO purpose I need that.

Can anybody help me to implement SSR in this boilerplate

Comment: If possible try using CRA

Comment: @RajSaraogi My application is already developed, I don't want to change anything in the core

Comment: you can integrate `express` and deploy using that for SSR

Comment: This might help? It guide how to pre-render your code into static html. https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/pre-rendering-into-static-html-files

Comment: @Bhawna: did you find the solution for this? I used react-boilerplate before and familiar with it, now I'm going to start a new project and it's best to stay with what I was already familiar with. But I also worry about SEO later, so SSR is a must

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a express server and prerender the react app in that server and after that you can manage to have SSR.
it's not a easy procedure at all. and very depends on libraries that you've used in your project. Some libraries are not support SSR.For instance Element-react and open street map are not supporting SSR.

[This Link](https://flaviocopes.com/react-server-side-rendering/) may help you